# NSWindowGraphicsContext object overreleased while already deallocating

Tags: swift, macos, memory-management

When switching between apps in OS X (Sierra, High Sierra), my mac app crashes with error,

objc[22408]: NSWindowGraphicsContext object 0x60000022d940 overreleased while already deallocating; break on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug
APP_NAME(22408,0x700008f8c000) malloc: *** error for object 0x6040000e9580: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Help to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you tried to set the breakpoints in `objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error` and `malloc_error_break ` as the error message suggests?

Comment: @mschmidt : yes, I have added that breakpoint. But I'm not getting any clue.

Comment: That breakpoint stops at **Foundation`clearPointerAt:**